# c# Must declare the scalar variable "@Kundenname"

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I am trying to get a little tool to work, for our little company.

This should fill data from a DataGridView into a SQL Server Standard database.
Reading out the SQL table is working fine, but I can't get the tool to write the values.

I get the error mentioned in the title.

Here the code:

```
var kdNummer = new SqlParameter("Kundennummer", SqlDbType.Int);
var kdName = new SqlParameter("Kundenname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
var kdMail = new SqlParameter("Kundenmail", SqlDbType.VarChar);
var kdTele = new SqlParameter("Telefon", SqlDbType.VarChar);

string kdquery = "INSERT INTO Kunden VALUES (@Kundennummer, @Kundenname, @Kundenmail, @Telefon)";

using (SqlConnection updatedb = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=updatedb;User ID=;Password="))
{
    updatedb.Open();

    for (int i = 0;i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
        using(SqlCommand NrDaten = new SqlCommand(kdquery, updatedb))
        {
            kdNummer.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Kundennummer"].Value;                     
            NrDaten.Parameters.Add(kdNummer);

            NrDaten.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        using (SqlCommand NameDaten = new SqlCommand(kdquery, updatedb))
        {
            kdName.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Kundenname"].Value;
            NameDaten.Parameters.Add(kdName);

            NameDaten.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        using (SqlCommand MailDaten = new SqlCommand(kdquery, updatedb))
        {
            kdMail.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Kundenmail"].Value;
            MailDaten.Parameters.Add(kdMail);

            MailDaten.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        using (SqlCommand TeleDaten = new SqlCommand(kdquery, updatedb))
        {
            kdTele.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Telefon"].Value;
            TeleDaten.Parameters.Add(kdTele);

            TeleDaten.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    updatedb.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query requires 4 parameters, but you're always only setting one (also please note that in the `SqlParameter` you need to have the `@` sign as well). Thus you get an error about missing parameters. Your code should probably look like this:

```
var kdNummer = new SqlParameter("@Kundennummer", SqlDbType.Int);
var kdName = new SqlParameter("@Kundenname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
var kdMail = new SqlParameter("@Kundenmail", SqlDbType.VarChar);
var kdTele = new SqlParameter("@Telefon", SqlDbType.VarChar);

string kdquery = "INSERT INTO Kunden VALUES (@Kundennummer, @Kundenname, @Kundenmail, @Telefon)";
using (SqlConnection updatedb = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    updatedb.Open();

    using (SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand(kdquery, updatedb))
    {
       insert.Parameters.Add(kdName);
       insert.Parameters.Add(kdNummer);
       insert.Parameters.Add(kdMail);
       insert.Parameters.Add(kdTele);

       for (int i = 0;i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
       {
           kdName.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Kundenname"].Value;
           kdNummer.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Kundennummer"].Value;                     
           kdMail.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Kundenmail"].Value;
           kdTele.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Telefon"].Value;

           insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
    }
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
string kdquery = "INSERT INTO Kunden VALUES (@Kundennummer, @Kundenname, @Kundenmail, @Telefon)";
using (SqlConnection updatedb = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    updatedb.Open();

    for (int i = 0;i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
       using (SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand(kdquery, updatedb))
       {
           insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kundenname", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Kundenname"].Value); 
           insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kundennummer", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Kundennummer"].Value); 
           insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kundenmail", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Kundenmail"].Value);
           insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefon", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Telefon"].Value);

           insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: I modified the long version of the code for maximum re-use of instances. Otherwise you get the errors mentioned in your comment.

Comment: I tried to pack that all into one statement before the code looks like now. But i got an error where it said that the SqlParameter is already in another ParameterCollection. I Tried it with your code aswell, but now it again says, that the Parameters are already in another ParameterCollection :(

Comment: @jasonX2000 Did you try the short version in my answer as well? I'm going to update the long solution as well.

Comment: @Torsten Dittmar
That seems seems to work, just had to change AddWidthValue to AddWithValue. :)
It runs in another error wich says:
Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated.

The statement has been terminated.

But when i got this error done, i can say more.

Comment: @JasonX2000 Going to fix that. It's a copy&paste typo :-) The other error means that the value you're trying to add to the table is longer than the field in the table. Shorten the text or increase field length.

Comment: Thx, thats right. Kundenname was to short. The code works to :)